# What is stored in FrontEnd memory?

Tags: front-end, memory

I quit the kernel, and closed all notebooks, leaving only the startup window. Yet when I open a new notebook, `MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd]` reveals that the FrontEnd still takes up lots of memory.

What exactly is stored in the FrontEnd, and how do I clear the memory without completely restarting Mathematica?

Comment: I recently started using Datasets and noticed that they seem to use significant FrontEnd memory as the complete data is put into the cell. Can anybody confirm this?